# Не отображается текст страницы в excel но в блокноте он есть

Tags: python, csv, lxml

В скрипте для парсинга сайта в excel колонка с именем продуктов не выводитcя name.text, но если убрать .text выводится класс но без имени .Файл расширения csv.
Если открывать этот же файл например блокнотом - name.text в нем есть.
Получилась так : скрипт вписывает имя продукта,цену с скидкой,без скидки, и процент скидки в файл .csv.В если открыть файл через блокнот - там будет вся нужная информация, но вот если открывать черех excel название товара не выводится но остальная информация остается.

```
with open ("epic_parser.csv",'a', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file,delimiter=";")
    writer.writerow(
        (
            name.text,
            p_currency,
            p_currency_old,
            procent,
            link
        )
    )
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос, чтобы можно было воспроизвести вашу проблему и найти адекватный ответ. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Значит проблема была в следующем, - выше была еще часть кода которая создавала ячейки в которые записывались данные с `encoding='utf-8'`.То есть мне нужно было всего то убрать `encoding='utf-8'` с поледующей части кода и так же добавить к `name.text.strip()`.

Comment: Это домыслы, а не ответ.

Comment: Это сработало - значит ответ